# Как отодвинуть вертикальные ссылки, так как на скрине ниже?

Tags: css, перенос-слов

Мне нужно понять, как перенести текст с помощью css в нужное месторасположение

[image: Это как должно быть (1-й скрин)]

[image: А это как оно есть сейчас (2-ой скрин)]

Comment: Должно быть, как на верхнем скриншоте, а ниже скриншот, как оно сейчас есть

Answer (score 1):

вы бы код приложили, чтобы понять структуру

потому что можно переносить через

1. `position: absolute`
2. `margin`
3. `padding`
4. `vertical-align`
5. `line-height`
6. дочерние свойства `flex`

и т.д.